# Extracting url by specifying a keyword

Tags: java, regex, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I want to extract url of a facebook page by giving a keyword. Eg if I specify a keyword like "gulab jamun" on facebook can I get the url of that page.I tried different ways but I don't even know that is it possible. So can anyone help me for resolving this issue.I tried that using existing API's too restfb and facebook4j but I think it's not possible through that. can any one help me

Comment: So, you want to get what exactly? The path?

Comment: @fge yes if i gave gulab jamun as my input it console then it should print https://www.facebook.com/pages/Gulab-jamun/108035329224130 as output or other page which is also related page like this https://www.facebook.com/GulabJamunOfficial

Comment: Uhm, hold on, what URL do you want to build out of this input? You may want to use a URI template if so. Something like `http://facebook.com/search?q=something`? Please edit your question

Comment: @fge i edited my ques nw currently iam pasting the url and getting the id as o/p. but know i want to use without using url by typing the keyword I should get access to its url ...only url

Comment: I think you either need a list of all the urls on facebook to do this, or put the keywords into facebook's search, take the url of the search results and filter on this list of urls.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have no success with how you tried it... The RegEx should be passed where?

A solution might be to use the Search API for Pages (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/#types), for example like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=gulab+jamun&type=page&access_token={YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

Then you can filter the results for the Page names of interest. To get the URL, you need to request the Page details per Page as follows:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{PAGE_ID_FROM_RESULT}?fields=id,name,link
```

A one-step solution is as far as I know not possible.

Comment: i dn't undaestand. I'm passing the url each time too get the id for further processing....using regex i did that. and nw i want to get the url by specifying the keyword eg:chocolate then it should redirect to that specific page..I need only the url of that page

Comment: after extracting id i have some further process to do which all i mentioned above. and that's not the real problem..i want to get id of a required page which now i'am passing manually